# Is it possible to check more than two conditions in having clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

When I am trying the below query

```
select column2 
from table1 
group by column2 
having count(column3) = count(column1) and column5 in (1,2)
```

I am getting this error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

What should I write in order to get result i.e. column2 which satisfies both the conditions

`i.e. (count(column3) = count(column1) and column5 in (5,6)`.

Comment: Your statement is ambiguous. Is you `HAVING` statement supposed to compare number of non-null values in column1 and column3 for rows that have column5 value of 1 or 2? If so, you should move `column5 in (1,2)` to `WHERE`. Or is it meant to compare the non-null values only for those rows sets (`GROUP BY column2`) that have 1 or 2 in column 5 _at all_?. In this case you could use subselect or self-join.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select column2
from table1
where column5 in (1,2)
group by column2
having count(column3) = count(column1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually have use part that should be in where condition and not in having as below.

```
SELECT column2 
FROM table1 
WHERE column5 IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY column2 
HAVING COUNT(column3) = COUNT(column1)
```

Always use aggregate functions in having clause to do the validation within query and not in clause.

Answer (score 0):

you are using having and group by clauses together . That is alright. 
But you can add where clause in your query for below condition

```
column5 in (1,2)
```

Once you restructure your query like below and I hope you get your solution

```
select column2 where column5 in (1,2) -- here is your where condition
from table1 
group by column2 
having count(column3) = count(column1)
```